# Access HTML content placed inside script with Jquery, Json and loops

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

OK, so I'm struggling with this code here. I created a JSFiddle, but the json won't work there. Anyway, I believe I got enough info to be understood.

https://jsfiddle.net/9zor6bcu/3/

JS:

```js
$.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    var htmls;
    htmls = '<div class="rl_grupo"><h3 class="rl_empresa"> Texto falso </h3><p class="rl_assina"> usuário falso </p><p class="rl_documentos"> 5 falsidades <span>></span></p></div>';
    $(".rl_assina").html(item.title);
    $(".container-fluid").append(htmls);
    console.log(item.title);
  }
});
```

So I have: An html page, that I want to populate with data, from a JSON endpoint (in this example just a fake API). I can loop over the data; And in the console see the correct output (in my example, `item.title`). But I can't figure out how to append it in my html with said lines from JSON.

In the posted fiddle, it actually changed the second line of code from all my Divs to the same one. What I'm doing wrong, and how can I improve this code? I read that those inline `htmls` on scripts is a bad thing.

So, if someone can point to some better practice, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to set the `.rl_assina` in the context of the new element you want to append.

```js
$.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    var htmls;
    htmls = $('<div class="rl_grupo"><h3 class="rl_empresa"> Texto falso </h3><p class="rl_assina"> usuário falso </p><p class="rl_documentos"> 5 falsidades <span>></span></p></div>');
    htmls.find(".rl_assina").html(item.title);
    $(".container-fluid").append(htmls);
    console.log(item.title);
  }
});
```

Comment: hey man! Thanks for the fast answer. Exactly what I need. 

I can see that you put my html var elements inside a Jquery quotes (thus creating a Jquery object?) Maybe that was my error.... Will read about it right now! 

Thanks again, and I already marked this solution as the correct one for me

Comment: Happy to help :) You can read more about it in the api [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements). When you ran `$('.rl_assina')`, the result is **all** the nodes which fit to this selector. The needed change is to find the node only in the context of the new node you want to add. That's why we need to wrap it with `$`, then we can find **within** it the `.rl_assina`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I rewrote your code a bit, but here's how I'd do it. You want to iterate over your JSON data, and for each object, append text to a list.
I have hard-coded the data because a real API call can't be made from here, but you get the idea.

```js
const data = [
{
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: "sunt aut facere",
    body: "quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae"
},
{
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: "qui est esse",
    body: "est rerum tempore vitae sequi sint nihil"
},
{
    userId: 1,
    id: 3,
    title: "ea molestias quasi",
    body: "et iusto sed quo iure voluptatem occaecati"
}]

const $rl_grupo = $("ul.rl_grupo")

// $.getJSON('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', function(data) {
     data.forEach(obj => {
         $rl_grupo.append(`<li>
              <h3 class="title">${obj.title}</h3>
              <p>${obj.body}</p>
         </li>`)
    }) 
// });
```

```css
.rl_grupo {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #426caf; }
  .rl_grupo .rl_empresa {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 10px 0px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: black; }
  .rl_grupo .rl_assina {
    color: #426caf;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px; }
  .rl_grupo .rl_documentos {
    background-color: #4e79bc;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center; }
    .rl_grupo .rl_documentos span {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="rl_grupo"></ul>
```